# Positioning action buttons on right hand side of a table really is user friendly?

Tags: usability, tables, action-items

We are designing an application which has multiple tables and there are multiple action items like the view, edit, etc.

Placing the action buttons on the right side of the table will not be the best option as the number of columns increases the width of the table increases which introduces a vertical scroll that hides the buttons.

[image]

So, keeping the action buttons on the right-hand side will be user-friendly? Or it has to be kept on the left-hand side so the buttons are always visible.

Comment: Action button in the table is placed on the right. A user will first scan the data and if any action is required to be taken user will click edit/update/delete/view buttons available. It's bad user experience when the user encounters action button first and then the user will scan the data and see if necessary any action is to be taken. Again user to come at the start where the user had encountered the button and take necessary action. In this case, the time taken to complete the task will be more than compared to action button placed on the right. Hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having worked a lot with tables, usually, the **edit interaction** is shown to the **right side**, like Dropbox for example. This is a matter of discoverability and where the user would expect to find these buttons.

My question would be is why the user would need to click the view button. **Why don't the user just click on the item?**

[image: dropbox]

It is also interesting to see what happens to the previous state: hiding the checkboxes and they appear only when the user hovers over the row.

[image: dropbox-2]

Comment: Good answer. I'd go a little further: Except in special circumstances, give each row a single control: click it to go to the "view" page. Move "edit" out of this table and onto the View page. And consider removing the checkboxes altogether, unless there's a very compelling reason to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should depend on how many times do user need to click these buttons, and where are the buttons(or menus and other action items) in the rest of the page. General rule is to keep the action items consistent. If your page normally has action items on left, then grid should have action items on left too, and vice versa.

Other than that, you must consider the selection check box as an action item as well. Is user allowed to make changes to multiple rows in one go. If yes, then your selection box should be as close to action button as possible. If no, then you should remove the selection checkbox entirely.